# Cutting out a Border using CSS trick

Tags: html, css

### The Problem...

I am trying to place `div`'s over a border, whilst leaving a gap on either side of each `div`. See here:

[image: Border Cut Out]

***Notice the gap on either side of the black divs.***

I cannot see a possible solution to this, other than the obvious two options of:

1. Place a border over the full width, then overlay an image with a background to hide the border behind
2. Or, separate the border into columns and then just add a margin (probably the best solution in my case)

### What I have tried...

Well as I am coming to SO hoping to be advised *a cool CSS trick*, I have not tried anything as I do not know where to start... Hence, *a cool CSS trick*...

### My Question (If it is not already clear)

Are there any methods **(other than the ones mentioned above)**, or cool tricks to achieve what I have illustrated in the image above?

***If there is no solution other than the methods I have already stated, please do not waste your time answering this question as I am more than capable of writing this code myself and other SO users are far more in need of your help :-)***

### Update

Here is a jsFiddle show what it looks like **without the gaps that I want**:

http://jsfiddle.net/BDt7v/

Comment: Create a jsfiddle with this.

Comment: I think you should be able to do something like using margins on the squares.

Comment: @AleksG How can I create a jsFiddle when there is no knowing what the HTML/CSS should be. There are several ways one could format the HTML for this...

Comment: Create one way that you tried and add the link to the question.

Comment: @AleksG I cannot see how that would work as the margin will not cover up the red border...

Comment: post your HTML and CSS code

Comment: @Sowmya As I mentioned, there is no code at present as there are so many ways this could be formatted. However, I will write the code now and post it up in the next few mins :-)

Comment: U meant to say, u want those gap next to the div?

Comment: @Sowmya Yes I suppose so :-D

Comment: @AleksG See my update with jsFiddle attached. I cannot see how this will help as the end HTML/CSS will probably look nothing like this...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this: Let's "cut out" the border left and right of the divs by overlaying it with some generated content - each div gets a :before and :after generated content pseudo-element, and those we style with a height of zero and a white border-top and a gray border-bottom of half the red border width - and then we just position them absolutely ... [here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CBroe/spfTx/1).

```
<div id="outer">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>

#outer {
    margin-top:50px;
    padding-bottom:50px;
    border-top:4px solid red;
    background:#ccc;
    text-align:center;
}
#outer div {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:-27px 25px 0 25px;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:#000;
}
#outer div:after, #outer div:before {
    content:" ";
    position:absolute;
    top:23px;
    width:5px;
    height:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    border-top:2px solid #fff;
    border-bottom:2px solid #ccc;
}
#outer div:after {
    left:-5px;
}
#outer div:before {
    right:-5px;
}
```

Comment: This is fantastic and the sort of thing I thought might be suggested. So +1 and thank you! However, there is one tiny little hitch which may make this fail. The part that is white (`#fff`) is actually going to be a textured background (`background-image: url(xxx) repeat;`)... Does this mess up your solution? Thank you so far :-D

Comment: In addition, the HTML that I have used is the HTML I will be using given what is going to be contained in each `div`.. Will this prevent your solution from working?

Comment: Actually, to make this slightly simpler (I think) with the textured background behind, I actually want to the `#ccc` part to extend up to be inline with the top of the red line...

Comment: In fact, I think I have sorted it by removing your top border and increasing the `border-bottom` width...

Comment: Yes, if you are willing to make that little compromise, it's quite easy. With a background image and the gray part _not_ extending to the top of the read line, it is also possible __if__ the background texture is fixed in regard to the viewport (not sure if possible for what you have in mind) - then we can replace the white border-top of the generated content by a height of 2px and give them the same fixed background, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/CBroe/spfTx/2/

Comment: But if fixing the background image is not an option, then the positions of the div elements would have to be known to you exactly beforehand - then the background image could be positioned for each of the generated contents "manually", so that each of them just shows that little part of the background image that's required in that exact position to still achieve the effect.